# Flash to Html5 Codes

Tags: flash, html5-canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            'codebase','http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0',
            'width','490',
            'height','450',
            'src','<?php echo PATH_IMAGE_USER_PICTURE.$avatar['picture']?>',
            'movie','<?php echo PATH_IMAGE_USER_PICTURE.$avatar['picture']?>',
            'wmode','transparent',
            'menu', 'false',
            'quality','high',
            'pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer'
        );
</script>
```

I have .php file and I want to run this file in html5 without flash player. It is flash support but I need to take support from html5 without flash. Thanks for comments !

Comment: There is no simple `from Flash to HTML` route

Comment: What does flash do with the avatar image or movie? And what are they themselves like? We cannot give an answer without knowing what the code does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to add it all because the code in the file was too much. It runs a swf file in the user interface.

Comment: OK, an .swf file is not a normal image or movie, it contains an animation created with Adobe Flash. If it is containing just an simple avatar image you could use that image as a normal image, but I guess it is animated somehow?

Comment: Yes it is animated. These codes from a game files. Users have items and various objects on them when we open the user interface, they show them in motion and do this process through flash. I want to run this without flash.

Comment: Most animations, previously done in Flash, are now possible in HTML/CSS/Javascript. It's easy when it is a simple animation, but can become highly complex. Without an example of the actual animation we cannot help you.

Comment: is there any way I can get this to you, and thank you for your answers.

Comment: You could film the flash movie, and post that movie online somewhere. Youtube, Vimeo? Some people might still be able to play a flash animation, so they would only need to have access to the .swf file. Please do not focus on me personally, I am probably not the one who is going to help you create a similar animation in HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need an alternative to Flash Player (because of EOL) or do you **need it to be HTML5**?

If you're looking for an alternative which *can* run .swf's seamlessly inside of a browser, check out [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs) and [Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.io).

But if you **need** an *HTML5* export, for porting to mobile/game consoles etc. consider looking into [Haxe](https://haxe.org/). It's not automatic but [this post](https://community.openfl.org/t/step-by-step-procedure-to-convert-a-flash-game-to-html5/11371/5) is very a good summary. Also if you're only converting an uninteractive animation, maybe [Zoë](https://www.createjs.com/zoe) might be useful as well.

Comment: Further reading, Data Horde has a very long list called the Flash Player Emergency Kit: https://datahorde.org/?page_id=1244 you might be able to find other solutions on there as well